# MYSQL replication for production server with both server active

Tags: mysql, replication

I want to know whether below is feasible?

I have two production MYSQL version: 5.5.52 databases. both have two schema (schema1 and schema2). 
If 
1. I replicate data from server1 schema1 to server2 schema1
2. I give read access to a robotic user on server2 - schema1 and write access on server2 - schema2.
3. I run select queries on various tables on server2 - schema1 and create a master resultant table on server2 schema2.

Will it impact server1 at all? 
will it cause data - corruption? 
is above solution feasible?
I want to do this so that I can reduce load from server1.

Comment: Why should anything you change in a DB on server2 affect the DB on server1 at all?

Comment: I don't have much idea about replication. I want to know whether the above solution feasible and won't disrupt replication in anyway